How to clear/erase the input value when using jquery datepicker and the input is readonly
I have an input that as soon as the value is changed it submits the value and is saved in our database, therefore we can only allow date format values, and the best tool is using datepicker with a readonly input. the only issue is that once a date is set it cannot be removed (in our case is ok to have empty dates).
<input class="datepicker" readonly="readonly" type="text" />

<script>
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-100:+20",
        changeYear: true 
    });
</script>

Is there a method part of datepicker that enables a way to erase the value without interacting with the input, or any other idea on how to accomplish this goal without creating new buttons or complicated UI elements?
Please keep in mind that this question is not about security implications, or if this is the best way to mantain the data integrity of our database, it is a JS / Jquery question. Thanks.

Your question is not very clear. Your first problem is that as soon as the input is changed, the value gets submitted. Yet, you want the ability to change the value before it's submitted. It seems you have to prevent auto-submitting, but since you have not shown us the code that does that, it's hard to help you with that problem.
The 2nd issue is you want the ability to clear the selected value, but you don't want it to be via interacting with the input field, nor by any new button or UI element. How, then, would you like it to work? Not the underlying mechanics, but from a UI perspective?

@kmoser, the issue is that as a read-only field the input text cannot be erased, only modified usng the datepicker calendar, we need a way to erase the input text into an empty field.

Why not add a button and Javascript that detects when the button is clicked and sets the value of the input field to blank?

That's part of the question, how to do it without adding extra UI/UX elements. I found a solution I am posting it ASAP.

In order to erase the value of the input that has readonly we can add a keyup listener to the datepicker object and detect if the delete or backspace keys were pressed, if so we can erase the value by using the _clearDate() method available from Jquery's datepicker.
<input class="datepicker" readonly="readonly" type="text" />

<script>
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-100:+20",
        changeYear: true
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        // Allow to erase the date with backspace or delete when the field is readonly
        if($(this).attr('readonly') === 'readonly' && (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)) {
            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
        }
    });
</script>

Here is the source where I got the _clearDate() solution:
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3999/

Is $(this).attr('readonly') === 'readonly' necessary to test?

Yes, there might be other datepicker inputs that are not readonly and the user has total freedom to edit the value, in my case I am using a class that applies to ALL datepickers, if the selector was an ID then I agree it would be useless.
